# Move Secure Notes items from Keychain of one Mac to another?

Tags: macos, security, keychain, migration, import

I have a keychain created, to hold a bunch of Secure Notes items. These are *not* in the default keychain files created by Apple.

In previous versions of macOS, I was able simply drag the keychain file from one Mac to a new Mac. Now in macOS Mojave, this is not working. When I drag the `my_own_keychain.keychain-db` from my home folder > Library > Keychains on the old Mac, and place it in the same location on the new Mac, the Keychains app fails to recognize it.

How can I get my own keychain file moved from old Mac to new Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Keychain Access.app` > `File` > `Add Keychain…`

[image: screenshot of Keychain Access.app > File > Add Keychain]

You got it half-way right.

1. Quit Keychain Access.app, just to be safe.
2. Locate your keychain file, named `whatever.keychain-db` as you mentioned.
3. Get a copy of that file onto your new Mac, perhaps via a thumb drive.
4. Put that file in your home folder, in `Library` folder, in `Keychains` folder.
   In other words:
    `~/Library/Keychains/your_keychain_name_goes_here.keychain-db`
5. Open Keychain Access.app on that new Mac.
6. Choose `File` > `Add Keychain…`.
7. In the file-picker dialog, choose the file you just placed in the `Keychains` folder.

We are not really importing or doing any processing here. We are merely informing the *Keychain Access* app about the existence of this additional keychain file.